# C++: Binary operator overloading using member function

Tags: c++, class, overloading, private, operator-keyword

I've searched stackoverflow a bit and found some topics similar to what I am doing. However, I just do not understand yet the probably very simple errors I made.

Can you please help me out? As you can see I make really basic mistakes.

The function is for practice purposes only. I want to have a class for points with `x`, `y` coordinates in double data type, these are privates.

To practice operator overloading/member function based operator access to privates, I wrote the following code.

In the end, I just want to print out the results of the addition of each of the coordinates `x` and `y` of two points.

What are the mistakes that I am making?

Thank you in advance for any hints.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class point{
    
    public:
        // this operator adds a point "p2" to the point of class "point"
        // OVERLOADING BINARY + USING A MEMBER FUNCTION:
        point operator+(point p){ // n is the 2nd number in the addition
            return point(x+p.x, y+p.y); // equals (this->x+p2.x, ...)
        }
        
    // private numbers 
    private:
        //declaration and initialization of x and y:
        double x=1.1,y=2.2;
};

int main()
{
    // Create two new points:
    point *p1 = new point ();
    point *p2 = new point ();
    
    cout << "The result of the addition is: " << (*p1+*p2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Currently the error I get is:

```
In member function ‘point point::operator+(point)’: main.cpp:16:38:
error: no matching function for call to ‘point::point(double, double)’
return point(x+p.x, y+p.y); // equals (this->x+p2.x, ...)
```

Comment: The error basically tells you that `point` doesn't have a constructor that takes 2 doubles. Which is true. There is also no overload for `operator<<` to print a `point`. Compilers don't do magic for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like churill pointed out, you missed implementing two things:

First you need to implement a constructor for your point class that takes 2 doubles:

```
point(double x, double y)
  : x(x), y(y)
{}
```

The above constructor is using [initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and does the same as this:

```
point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

and don't forget to implement the default constructor again since otherwise C++ will not find it anymore and your code will fail to compile

```
point() {}
```

Second You need to overwrite the "<<" operator which will allow you to cout your point object:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const point& p) {
    os << "(" << p.x << ',' << p.y << ')'; // will output (x,y)
    return os;
}
```

if you put all the above in your point class as public it should compile without a problem

Comment: Thank you for your hints, I've definitely learned something. Additional questions: 
1. So in case I leave the default constructor away what happens?

Comment: 2. As I understood not only do I need to create private attributes. Am I right that the constructor line you suggested can be translated into primitive language like this: "take the private attribute x,y (expect doubles), and make the publicly available x and y be equal to the values of those private attributes"?

Comment: 1. Your program propably wouldn't compile since it can't find the default constructor that you called by "point *p1 = new point ();"

Comment: 2. The constructor just passes the x and y to the always private attributes. I added an alternative constructor to my answer which maybe will make things clearer

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!